# Improving pin input component

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a component with four input fields that can take only numbers. Upon input, the focus jumps from the current input field to the next one. Deleting works as well (when the Backspace is pressed) - deleting the value in the current field will move the focus to the previous one.

The problem I have is that the current implementation is pretty static meaning that some values are hardcoded. If you look [at this demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-guxwjn), you'll see that each `(input)` event sends a hardcoded index. The same with each `(delete)`.

Another limitation is that if I want to add a fifth input, I need to copy one of the existing inputs and made some adjustments.

So my challenge right know is how to make this more dynamic and flexible. Like specifying how many inputs there should be. Also don't hardcode the indexes but be able to figure that out from the code.

Any suggestions for how to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this sample, I'm using a reactive form. I would make this a separate component, and you would just pass the number of digits to the component, which then handles everything else. You probably need to pass the digits to the parent component, and you can use `@Output` for that. You don't NEED to create a component, but I would, for cleanness sake :)

So we could create a `HelloComponent` (name just gotten from stackblitz template) where we would build the form, push as many form controls to the array as you have specified:

```
@Input() numOfDigits;

@ViewChildren('inputs') inputs: QueryList<any>;

confirmCodeForm: FormGroup;

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  this.confirmCodeForm = this.fb.group({
    digits: this.fb.array([]) // create empty form initially
  });
}

ngOnInit() {
  // push form controls to the formarray
  for (let i = 0; i< this.numOfDigits; i++) {
    (this.confirmCodeForm.get('digits') as FormArray).push(this.fb.control(null))
  }
}
```

Then handling the events and checking that valid numbers, change focus on field etc, which is fired on `keydown`:

```
check(index, field, event) {
  if (isNaN(parseInt(event.key, 10)) && event.key !== 'Backspace') {
    event.preventDefault();
  } 
  else if (field.value && event.key !== 'Backspace') {
    if (index < this.inputs.toArray().length - 1) {
      this.inputs.toArray()[index + 1].nativeElement.focus();
    }
  }
  else if (event.key === 'Backspace') {
    if (index > 0) {
      field.setValue(null)
      this.inputs.toArray()[index - 1].nativeElement.focus();
    } else {
      console.log('first field');
    }
  }
}
```

In the template we would then iterate the form array and then we are done!

```
<form (ngSubmit)="confirmCode(confirmCodeForm.value)" [formGroup]="confirmCodeForm">
  <div formArrayName="digits">
    <input *ngFor="let field of confirmCodeForm.get('digits').controls; 
                   let i = index" 
           #inputs 
           [maxLength]="1"
           [formControlName]="i" 
           (keydown)="check(i, field, $event)">
  </div>
</form>
```

No this component is easy to use with just

```
<hello [numOfDigits]="4"></hello>
```

### [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vzjq6t?file=src/app/hello.component.html)

Comment: Thank you for your tips. This approach looks way better and it's also more flexible. If I find the time, I'll try to adjust it a bit more and release it as an open source component.

Comment: @AT82 can you elaborate more on situation when Backspace is pressed? When Backspace is pressed digit from current input is removed and the previous one - the one to which focus is moved.

Answer (score -1):

What you are looking for the the `*ngFor` directive.
See: https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data#showing-an-array-property-with-ngfor

I've also forked your example and modified it:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ug7b69?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

However, you will run into other issues with the `@HostListener`s approach, as you will soon notice in the example. I would suggest looking into the `ngModel` directive and/or Angular Forms (`FormGroup`, `FormControl`, etc.) for a safer way of detecting those input changes and reacting to them.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I already tried `ngFor` and the result wasn't as good. The problem is apparent in your fork as well. Maybe it will work better if I indeed look into `FormControl`.